# How to call a method of a controller in a method of another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, action

I want to call a method of one controller in another controller's method, and also pass parameters like below:

Controller A:

```
@var
def methodA
  update(@var)
end
```

Controller B:

```
def update(var)
  var1 = var
end
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Since `update` is an instance method, you should have an instance of `B`, on which you want to call `update`. And you should just explicitly call the method on it. But you have not presented that instance in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not define the shared method in `ApplicationController` instead and call it in both controllers as they each inherit it's methods. Like so:

ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protected

  def update(var)
    var1 = var
  end
end
```

Other Controllers:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController    
  def some_method()
    @var = 'something'
    update(@var)
  end
end


class SomeOtherController < ApplicationController    
   def some_method()
     @var = 'something'
     update(@var)
   end
 end
```